# How to use a method from another class to print an ArrayList in the Main class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I have a problem I have been working on for a long time and I cannot seem to figure it out.
I need to make a method called shownodesandlinks in the GraphData class or the Node class and then print out the arraylist in the graphdata class in the Main class.

How do I do that? I can print the method but it is only spitting out **"at ruttsokning.Node.addNeighbour(Node.java:76)"** and not the data from the table I need. Here is my code, I have currently 3 classes.

**Main class**

```
    package ruttsokning;
    import ruttsokning.GraphData;
    import java.io.*;
    import ruttsokning.Node;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class Main {
     
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
        GraphData data = new GraphData();
        ArrayList<Node> graph = data.createGraph();
        data.shownodesandlinks(graph);
}
}
```

**GraphData class**

```
package ruttsokning;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import ruttsokning.Node;


public class GraphData {
    

    public ArrayList<Node> createGraph() {

        
        LinkedHashMap<String,Node> nodes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        nodes.put("bole", new Node("Böle bibliotek",           60.2008, 24.9359));
        nodes.put("vall", new Node("Vallgårds bibliotek",      60.1923, 24.9626));
        nodes.put("berg", new Node("Berghälls bibliotek",      60.1837, 24.9536));
        nodes.put("tolo", new Node("Tölö bibliotek",           60.1833, 24.9175));
        nodes.put("oodi", new Node("Centrumbiblioteket Ode",   60.174,  24.9382));
        nodes.put("rich", new Node("Richardsgatans bibliotek", 60.1663, 24.9468));
        nodes.put("bush", new Node("Busholmens bibliotek",     60.16,   24.9209));


        HashMap<String,String[]> neighbours = new HashMap<>();
        neighbours.put("bole", new String[]{"tolo", "berg"});
        neighbours.put("vall", new String[]{"berg"});
        neighbours.put("berg", new String[]{"bole", "vall", "tolo", "oodi"});
        neighbours.put("tolo", new String[]{"bole", "berg", "oodi", "bush"});
        neighbours.put("oodi", new String[]{"tolo", "berg", "rich"});
        neighbours.put("rich", new String[]{"oodi", "bush"});
        neighbours.put("bush", new String[]{"tolo", "rich"});


        ArrayList<Node> graph = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String id : nodes.keySet()) {

            nodes.get(id).setId(id);

            for (String neighbor : neighbours.get(id)) {
                nodes.get(id).addNeighbour(nodes.get(neighbor));
            }

            graph.add(nodes.get(id));
        }

        return graph;
    }

    public void shownodesandlinks(ArrayList<Node> graph) {
        for (Node node : graph) {
            System.out.println(node);
            // print node here
        }
    }
}
```

**Node class**

```
package ruttsokning;
import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    
    public class Node{
        
        static String name;
        private static double latitude;
        private static double longitude;
        static ArrayList<Node> neighbours;
        
        private Node next;
        
        public Node(String name, double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            setName(name);
            setLatitude(latitude);
            setLongitude(longitude);
            setNext(next);
        }
        
         public double getLatitude()
        {
            return latitude;
        }
         public double getLongitude()
        {
            return longitude;
        }
        
        public static String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        
         public ArrayList<Node> getNeighbours()
        {
            return neighbours;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name)
        {
            Node.name = name;
        }
        public void setLatitude(double latitude)
        {
            Node.latitude = latitude;
        }
        
        public void setLongitude(double longitude)
        {
            Node.longitude = longitude;
        }
          
        public void setNext(Node next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }
        
        public void addNeighbour(Node neighbours)
        {
            
            neighbours.addNeighbour(neighbours);
            
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
        }
}
```

Comment: this statement is *suspect*: `neighbours.addNeighbour(neighbours);` - probably missing a `this`l  like in `this.neighbours.addNeighbour(neighbours);`  (otherwise `addNeighbour` will be called recursively for ever until stack overflows)

Comment: also calling ONE node `neighbours` is confusing - it is only 1 (parameter of `addNeighbour`)

Comment: actually the statement should be `this.neighbours.add(neighbours);` (list don't have `addNeighbour()`) and, as [BambooleanLogic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66637330/15244370) wrote, the list is not being initialized (missing something like `this.neighbours = new ArrayList<>()`)

Comment: it cant be change to this.neighbours because it is static. I would have to use Node.neighbours however it is through in NullPointerException if I do

Comment: just rename the parameter (`neighbour` or `node`) - but I guess that `static` is wrong on all the fields - these should hardly be class fields/variables (or should all nodes have the same, share the same name, latitude, longitude, neighbours?)

Comment: Unrelated: please note that *details* matter in programming. Every char you put (or put not) into your code ... is there because you decided to put it there. So: always indent your code consistently. Dont use empty lines because you can, but because it makes sense (for example to group things together). Your code isnt too messy, but it starts to get messy. But you put up that code here for OTHERS to read. So please remember: for yourself but especially when giving code to others: make sure it "looks" clean. Because without that, people need more time reading your input than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`at ruttsokning.Node.addNeighbour(Node.java:76)` is part of a *stack trace*, a multi-line message that Java prints whenever your program has crashed. The message contains information about what kind of error has occurred, as well as which part of the system caused the crash.

In this case, the problem was presumably a `NullPointerException` in the method `addNeighbour`. This is due to you trying to add data into the list named `neighbours`, except that list is never initialized. It's always `null`, causing this error.

In the class `GraphData`, I can see that you have another list named `neighbours` that you do initialize with data. These are however completely separate things that happen to share a name.

The simplest solution seems to be to have `GraphData` make use of the other list instead of creating its own. This could be done by replacing the existing initialization with this:

```java
        Node.neighbours = new HashMap<>();
        Node.neighbours.put("bole", new String[]{"tolo", "berg"});
        Node.neighbours.put("vall", new String[]{"berg"});
        Node.neighbours.put("berg", new String[]{"bole", "vall", "tolo", "oodi"});
        Node.neighbours.put("tolo", new String[]{"bole", "berg", "oodi", "bush"});
        Node.neighbours.put("oodi", new String[]{"tolo", "berg", "rich"});
        Node.neighbours.put("rich", new String[]{"oodi", "bush"});
        Node.neighbours.put("bush", new String[]{"tolo", "rich"});
```

...and also update the reference to `neighbours` in the `for` loop to instead use `Node.neighbours`.

Comment: more probably it was a `StackOverflowException` - `neighbours` is not the list but the method parameter (list also does not have a method `addNeighbour`)

Comment: neighbours.get(id) did you mean this part to change to Node.neighbours? it is throwing an error if I change that.

Answer (score 0):

This method is causing (the first) problem:

```
public void addNeighbour(Node neighbours)
{
    neighbours.addNeighbour(neighbours);
}
```

<sup>above code is **not a correction**, just to show the problem</sup>

well called, `addNeighbour` will call the method `addNeighbour` (same method) of `neighbours`. This will again try to call `addNeighbour`, which will again call `addNeighbour`. ...

These chain will only terminate after the stack overflows (`StackOverflowException`, basically out of memory).

Probably it was meant to add the node to the list, that is

```
public void addNeighbour(Node newNeighbour)
{
    neighbours.add(newNeighbour);
}
```

but here we see the next problem - the list `neighbours` is not initialized and is `static` (urgent to learn the difference between static and non-static members!)

The list must be initialized

- in its declaration:
  `ArrayList<Node> neighbours = new Arraylist<>();`
- or constructor:
  `neighbours = new Arraylist<>();`

---

Fields being **static**: 
`static` fields are not associated to an instance, but to the class. In other words there is only one value (memory position), no matter how many instances were created. In that code all `Node`s  will share the same name, coordinates and neighbours!

Simple example (how not to do it):

```
class Node {
  static String name;
  Node(String newName);
    name = newName;
  }
}
```

the following code will print `second`, despite `n1` was created with `first`

```
Node n1 = new Node("first");
Node n2 = new Node("second");
System.out.println(n1.name);
```

`new Node("second")` is setting the field `name`, since it is `static` - there is only one field - `n1` is also using the same `name`, so it returns the last value set.

---

Solution: do remove `static` from all fields of `Node`, these should be instance variables, not class variables. (same for getters and setters for these fields)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, so I changed all the static variables in the node class. However that did not fix the issue.

Comment: have you tried the second snippet I posted -`neighbours.add(newNeighbour);` ? And the third oen too - `ArrayList<Node> neighbours = new Arraylist<>();` ?